# Jwt token: DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary NullPointerException on signWith method on token creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jwt

I have the following method for creating a JWT token during authentication:

```
private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, 
                           String subject) {
    JwtBuilder builder =  Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims)
            .setSubject(subject)
            .setIssuedAt(
                  new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    builder = builder
            .setExpiration(
                new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() +
                        1000 * 60 * 60 * 10));
    builder = builder
            .signWith(   
               SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, 
               SECRET_KEY);  //error on this line
    return builder.compact();
}
```

However I get a `NullPointerException` on the `builder.signWith()` line.

I'm not sure why. The `builder` after the `.setExpiration()` line is not null. I checked the debugger (breakpoint on the `.signWith()` line) and it seems to be fine:

[image]

The `claims` are not empty and contains the subject and dates:

[image]

This is the full error:

```
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/testproject_war_exploded] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(DatatypeConverter.java:296)
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64Codec.decode(Base64Codec.java:26)
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.signWith(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:99)
        at testproject.security.JwtUtil.createToken(JwtUtil.java:52)
```

Comment: maybe SECRET_KEY is null?

Comment: @Maurice No it's not: see the first debugger pic

Comment: This seems to be a weird issue,I would suggest not to use builder = builder.setExpiration , you can benefit from builder pattern and set all the values in one line itself.something like below code Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET_KEY).compact()

Comment: @NageshTripathi It was the one-liner that originally gave me the error; I only split it into several lines to make sure `builder` is never null

Answer (score 1):

This is how you sign a JWT token with a private key using HS256 :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    KeyPair keyPair = Keys.keyPairFor(HS256);
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
    Jwts.builder().signWith(privateKey);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using jjwt 0.9.1 and Java 11. Solved by switching from Java 11 to Java 1.8.

My development machine was MacOS Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue, I changed my function to this

```
    public String getTokenFromClaims(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {
        claims.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Key is" + k + "value" + v));
        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + expiresIn))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, Base64.getEncoder().encode(secret.getBytes())).compact();
    }
```